# Finding a domain for a function with complex root

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following function
$$ \lambda(L,k)= \sqrt{k^2+i\frac{a}{L}}$$
with $k\in \mathbb{C}$, $L\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a$ being a constant in $\mathbb{R}_+$
and I am trying to find a domain, where this complex root is defined (i.e. not negative real).
Since I want my values for $L$ to be small i had the idea to say, that for every $K$ there exists an $\varepsilon>0$, such that for
$$\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{R}\subset\left(B_K(0)\times \left(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon \right)  \right) $$
the function is welldefined. I think this might work, since for very small values of $L$ the $i\frac{a}{L}$ becomes really big. And with such big values for $i\frac{a}{L}$, also the imaginary part of $k^2$ must be really big, for the radicant to become negative real. Therefore i assume that if I bound the values for $k$ in a certain ball with radius $K$, I always find a $\varepsilon$ small enough, such that the function does not become negative real.

I probably just wanted to write it down in order to see if this makes any sense. If it does I wonder if there was a proper way to prove this?

Comment: Are you claiming that negative real numbers do not have square roots?

Comment: Wikiperdia says: "The principal square root function is thus defined using the nonpositive real axis as a branch cut. The principal square root function is holomorphic everywhere except on the set of non-positive real numbers (on strictly negative reals it isn't even continuous)." thats what i meant..